# separate a nested array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of data in the below format

```
output = [
  {
    tasks: [
      {
        chartType: "bar",
        code: "p1",
        showInReport: true,
        value: 2827.5
      },
      {
        chartType: "line",
        code: "p2",
        showInReport: true,
        value: 4394
      },
      {
        chartType: "pie",
        code: "p3",
        showInReport: true,
        value: 10975
      }
    ],
    time: "2020-07"
  },
  {
    tasks: [
      {
        chartType: "bar",
        code: "p1",
        showInReport: true,
        value: 3720.5
      },
      {
        chartType: "line",
        code: "p2",
        showInReport: true,
        value: 6086.5
      },
      {
        chartType: "pie",
        code: "p3",
        showInReport: true,
        value: 8741
      }
    ],
    time: "2020-08"
  },
  {
    tasks: [
      {
        chartType: "bar",
        code: "p1",
        showInReport: true,
        value: 6110.5
      },
      {
        chartType: "line",
        code: "p2",
        showInReport: true,
        value: 8781
      },
      {
        chartType: "pie",
        code: "p3",
        showInReport: true,
        value: 13362
      }
    ],
    time: "2020-09"
  }
]
```

I wish to split this array in two arrays based on the `chartType`. If `chartType = "pie"` separate the array:

```
pieData = [
  {
    tasks: [
      {
        chartType: "pie",
        code: "p3",
        showInReport: true,
        value: 10975
      }
    ],
    time: "2020-07"
  },
  {
    tasks: [
      {
        chartType: "pie",
        code: "p3",
        showInReport: true,
        value: 8741
      }
    ],
    time: "2020-08"
  },
  {
    tasks: [
      {
        chartType: "pie",
        code: "p3",
        showInReport: true,
        value: 13362
      }
    ],
    time: "2020-09"
  }
]
```

else

```
barLineData = [
  {
    tasks: [
      {
        chartType: "bar",
        code: "p1",
        showInReport: true,
        value: 2827.5
      },
      {
        chartType: "line",
        code: "p2",
        showInReport: true,
        value: 4394
      }
    ],
    time: "2020-07"
  },
  {
    tasks: [
      {
        chartType: "bar",
        code: "p1",
        showInReport: true,
        value: 3720.5
      },
      {
        chartType: "line",
        code: "p2",
        showInReport: true,
        value: 6086.5
      }
    ],
    time: "2020-08"
  },
  {
    tasks: [
      {
        chartType: "bar",
        code: "p1",
        showInReport: true,
        value: 6110.5
      },
      {
        chartType: "line",
        code: "p2",
        showInReport: true,
        value: 8781
      }
    ],
    time: "2020-09"
  }
]
```

My js knowledge is weak, So i don' t know how to do that.

Comment: did you try anything ?

Comment: [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is your friend here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `filter` to separate the objects by chart-type

```js
output = [ { tasks: [ { chartType: "bar", code: "p1", showInReport: true, value: 2827.5 }, { chartType: "line", code: "p2", showInReport: true, value: 4394 }, { chartType: "pie", code: "p3", showInReport: true, value: 10975 }, ], time: "2020-07", }, { tasks: [ { chartType: "bar", code: "p1", showInReport: true, value: 3720.5 }, { chartType: "line", code: "p2", showInReport: true, value: 6086.5 }, { chartType: "pie", code: "p3", showInReport: true, value: 8741 }, ], time: "2020-08", }, { tasks: [ { chartType: "bar", code: "p1", showInReport: true, value: 6110.5 }, { chartType: "line", code: "p2", showInReport: true, value: 8781 }, { chartType: "pie", code: "p3", showInReport: true, value: 13362 }, ], time: "2020-09", }, ];

let pie = [],
  nonPie = [];
output.forEach((o) => {
  nonPie.push({
    tasks: [
      ...o.tasks.filter((p) =>
        p.chartType == "pie"
          ? (pie.push({ tasks: [p], time: o.time }), false)
          : true
      ),
    ],
    time: o.time,
  });
});
console.log(pie);
console.log("-----------------------------");
console.dir(nonPie);
```

Comment: What do you mean by code `? (pie.push({ tasks: [p], time: o.time }), false)
          : true`
I don' t understand true, false Syntax

Comment: it's ternary operator it's equivalent to `if (p.chartType == "pie") {pie.push({ tasks: [p], time: o.time }) return false} else return true` it checks first for the condition if met it pushs the object to pie array else it returns the object let me know if you have any more questions

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to reduce the task array inside by checking the chartType property and add it to the main reducer next.

```js
const output = [
  {
    tasks: [
      {
        chartType: "bar",
        code: "p1",
        showInReport: true,
        value: 2827.5
      },
      {
        chartType: "line",
        code: "p2",
        showInReport: true,
        value: 4394
      },
      {
        chartType: "pie",
        code: "p3",
        showInReport: true,
        value: 10975
      }
    ],
    time: "2020-07"
  },
  {
    tasks: [
      {
        chartType: "bar",
        code: "p1",
        showInReport: true,
        value: 3720.5
      },
      {
        chartType: "line",
        code: "p2",
        showInReport: true,
        value: 6086.5
      },
      {
        chartType: "pie",
        code: "p3",
        showInReport: true,
        value: 8741
      }
    ],
    time: "2020-08"
  },
  {
    tasks: [
      {
        chartType: "bar",
        code: "p1",
        showInReport: true,
        value: 6110.5
      },
      {
        chartType: "line",
        code: "p2",
        showInReport: true,
        value: 8781
      },
      {
        chartType: "pie",
        code: "p3",
        showInReport: true,
        value: 13362
      }
    ],
    time: "2020-09"
  }
];

const { pie, nonPie } = output.reduce((acc, { tasks, time }) => {
    const reducedObj = tasks.reduce((r, c) => {
        if (c.chartType === 'pie') {
            r.pieTasks.push(c);
        } else {
            r.nonPieTasks.push(c);
        }
        
        return r;
    }, { pieTasks: [], nonPieTasks: [] });
    
    acc.pie.push({
        time,
        tasks: reducedObj.pieTasks
    });
    acc.nonPie.push({
        time,
        tasks: reducedObj.nonPieTasks
    });
    return acc;
}, { pie: [], nonPie: [] });

console.log('Pie chart data', pie);
console.log('Non pie chart data', nonPie);
```